# Wake on LAN & CISCO modem - WOL not possible?

Tags: wake-on-lan, wan

i have a problem since the guys from UPC changed my old cable modem with a new CISCO EPC 3208 model. (It's a VOIP cable modem & i have static IP from UPC/my ISP.) Since then, WOL over the internet works, but only for a few moments after i’ve shutdown the PC i’m trying to wake. (My PC  connects directly to this CISCO modem, i have no router between.) I know how to set up a "WOL over internet" environment (BIOS, network card settings, etc. - i use Wake On Lan Monitor when PC is "alive" to be sure my PC gets the Magic Packets from internet) - but if i shutdown my PC and wait few minutes, i can't wake up my PC anymore.
What would be the problem, any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you sending your WOL packet?   It kinda sounds like some device may not be forwarding the packet, because of timeout of some sort?  Perhaps ARP?

Comment: It seems like the CISCO modem after 2-3 minutes "forget" the connection to my PC's network card.

Comment: [Edited] I'm sending the WOL packets from my phone (i have a different 3G connection to access the internet), and it works right after i shutdown my PC (the PC wakes up). But after 3-4 minutes, it seems like the CISCO modem "forgets" the connection to my PC's network card. I don't know hot to access my CISCO modem's ARP... I even called my ISP (UPC Romania) to ask them about that issue, but they told me that WOL over internet should work... (Before this Cisco modem i had a Cisco modem+router from the same ISP, and when i set it in bridge mode, the WOL over internet has worked...)

Comment: Aren't the WOL packets sent as UDP packets to the network's broadcast address? I'm using this in a perl script to wakeup some PCs.

Comment: The Magic Packets are sent from my android phone with special WOL-programs (ex. Depicus), but they "hit" my PC only right after the PC-shutdown.

Comment: Can you show such a packet (captured with tcpdump or wireshark)? Can you send the wakeup from a server within the local net, so that you trigger it from outside only?